# Creating a custom progress indicator in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently i am trying to create a custom progress indicator in my ipad app.But currently there is no such controller available in ios sdk.

So how to create this ?[image]

Comment: Do you need to animate the progress bar? If not, you could probably just get away with having one UIImageView and changing it's image property as the user progresses through your flow.

Answer (score 2):

I have a really interesting vision of this - you need to create a `UIImageView` like the one on your picture and leave the areas that need to be highlighted transparent. You then put a blue `UIView` underneath it and using animation block you change its frame - kinda 'drag' it to the right - so it looks like it's filling the progress indicator. It's rather simple, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a CAShapeLayer to draw out your loading bar and then animate accordingly.

Joe Conway (formerly of Big Nerd Ranch) created a circular progress bar which can be found [here](https://github.com/stablekernel/STKSpinnerView)

I would recommend following along with the code he laid out for his project and mend it accordingly.